# React-pdf export Highcharts in SVG

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, react-pdf

There is a React project in which I want to export a chart in SVG format. I already use the React-pdf library in this project that I cannot replace. Could someone help me how I can pass the SVG content for the PDF document? I tried simple inserting the content into the Page and SVG tags but neither of them worked.

```
<Document>
  <Page>
    {chart.getSVG()}
  </Page>
</Document>
```

Another approach:

```
<Document>
  <Page>
    <Svg>
      {chart.getSVG()}
    </Svg>
  </Page>
</Document>
```

Here is a demo project for testing: https://playcode.io/1247515